# How to set custom categories to a scatter plot in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to set custom categories for my scatter plot in Power B by writing this measure

```
Categorize = 
VAR _threshold = 20
VAR _cat1 = "692145"
VAR _cat2 = "6f625a"
VAR _cat3 = "5b6770"
VAR _cat4 = "a12b2f"
RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        [Measure 1] && [Measure 2] < _threshold, _cat1,
        [Measure 1] < _threshold && [Measure 2] > _threshold, _cat2,
        [Measure 1] > _threshold && [Measure 2] < _threshold, _cat3,
        [Measure 1] && [Measure 2] > _threshold, _cat4
    )
```

Basically what I am trying to do is classify each quadrant below to its own category color[image]

However, when I go to the conditional formatting option in data colors, my `Categorize` measure is grayed out.

Is there a way I can modify my DAX to make this work?

Comment: Can you share sample data so that we can play with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't use a DAX formula to pass a color value.

What you can do is use a measure to assign a fixed value (a category) and then apply a color rule based on that.

I also think that some of the AND conditions in your formula are not working

```
Categorize = 
VAR _threshold = 20
VAR _cat1 = 1
VAR _cat2 = 2
VAR _cat3 = 3
VAR _cat4 = 4
RETURN
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        [Measure 1] < _threshold && [Measure 2] < _threshold, _cat1,
        [Measure 1] < _threshold && [Measure 2] > _threshold, _cat2,
        [Measure 1] > _threshold && [Measure 2] < _threshold, _cat3,
        [Measure 1] > _threshold && [Measure 2] > _threshold, _cat4
    )
```

And then you assign colors based on the measure: "Data Colors" --> "Conditional Formatting"

[image]

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Yes this works, thank you! This approach makes a bit more sense compared to how I was originally approaching it.